# Can I use analogRead to read a digital pin?

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread

analogRead(nGPIO_max + lockerVal) were nGPIO_max(maximum digital pins in Arduino Uno is 13) and lockerval is 2. Which pin is it reading?

Comment: 13 + 2 = 15, so pin 15.  I'll give you a clue: A0 is pin 14.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer the question in the title: No, you cannot use `analogRead()` to read a digital pin. A digital pin cannot behave as analog because it isn't connected to the ADC (Analog to Digital Converter).

If you call something equating to `analogRead(15)` on an Uno, then it should read pin `A1`. You can see the pin assignments in the board-specific versions of `pins_arduino.h` (shipped with the IDE):

```
static const uint8_t A0 = 14;
static const uint8_t A1 = 15;
static const uint8_t A2 = 16;
static const uint8_t A3 = 17;
static const uint8_t A4 = 18;
static const uint8_t A5 = 19;
static const uint8_t A6 = 20;
static const uint8_t A7 = 21;
```

Using those raw numbers directly is generally not a good idea though as it obscures your code's meaning, and will potentially make it non-portable to other boards. It's better to call something like `analogRead(A1)`.

It's worth noting that the Arduino library fudges the pin numbers slightly. Calling `analogRead(1)` has the same result as calling `analogRead(A1)`. That means that even if you *tried* to use `analogRead()` on a digital pin, it might actually end up reading an analog pin instead. Alternatively, it might just return a meaningless result, depending on the pin number you give it.